# How to delete the repeating entries from this SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my SQL Table like this

```
wordId     word        isOxford
--------------------------------
1214       pen            0
1215       pen            0
1216       bat            0
1217       bottle         1
1218       pen            1
1219       bottle         1
1220       rose           0
1221       rose           0
```

I want to remove all duplicate entries and the resultant table should have only distinct rows. The entry should be deleted if the row contains same word and `isOxford`. The resultant table should be like this.

```
wordId     word        isOxford
===================================
1214       pen             0    
1216       bat             0    
1217       bottle          1    
1218       pen             1    
1220       rose            0
```

Comment: Are you using SQL server or MySQL?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
    Id INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(3)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID),
    *
    FROM @T
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN >1

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T
```

Answer (score 4):

If, you are using SQL Server then you can use `row_number()` function :

```
delete t 
from (
       select *,
               row_number() over (partition by word, isOxford order by wordId) Seq 
       from table t 
     ) t
where Seq > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT wordId,word,isOxford 
FROM(
    SELECT wordId,word,isOxford
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY word, isOxford ORDER BY wordId)RN
    FROM Your_Table
    )D
WHERE D.RN = 1
```

Delete Using this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT wordId,word,isOxford
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY word, isOxford ORDER BY wordId)RN
    FROM Your_Table
    )
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: so which one should I run first? delete or the above code?

Comment: Thanks a lot Boss. Working

Answer (score 1):

If `wordId` is PK

You can make it on one query. Because `MIN(wordId)` function will get first data on the group.

```
SELECT MIN(wordId) as 'wordId',word,isOxford
FROM  T
GROUP BY word,isOxford
ORDER BY wordId
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00900/1*

DELETE use this.

```
DELETE t1 FROM T t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(wordId) as 'wordId',word,isOxford
  FROM  T
  GROUP BY word,isOxford
) t2 on t1.wordId = t2.wordId 
WHERE t2.wordId IS NULL;
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fcbb/1*